# UITableViewCell's contentView's content not visible when using UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have written a simple contact manager application that uses a `UITableView` to display the contacts.  Each contact is shown as a standard `UITableViewCell`; custom content is created as `UIButtons` and `UILabels` that are added as `subviews` of the cell's `contentView`.  My table `viewController's` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method includes:

```
UIButton *emailButton;
UITableViewCell *cell = 
        [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"My Identifier"];
if (cell == nil) 
   {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
     emailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [emailButton setImage:emailImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     emailButton.tag = EMAIL_BUTTON_TAG;
     emailButton.frame = emailButtonFrame;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:emailButton];
   } else {
     emailButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:EMAIL_BUTTON_TAG];
   }
... set various attributes of the cell, including the content of custom labels
... added as subviews of the contentView exactly as above
```

This works fine when rendering my table.  But I've also added a search bar to my app, set the search bar's controller appropriately, and set the `controller's` delegate back to this same `tableController` such that the exact same `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called when performing the searches, and of course I filter the set of cells to be displayed to match the query.

What I see is that when I perform a search, all of the content that I display by setting `cell.textLabel.text` or `cell.imageView.image` shows up perfectly in the table, but the emailButton or the labels that I added as `subviews` of the cell's `contentView` don't appear.  In the debugger, I can clearly see that these controls (the buttons and labels) exist at the time that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called while search filtering is going on.  But the controls don't render.

I feel there must be something very subtle in the interactions between table cells and the `searchView`, but I'm missing it.

Comment: can you tell a little more about **cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called when performing the searches**. You are filtering an array, then calling tableView's reloadData and not calling **cellForRowAtIndexPath** yourself, right?

Comment: Under normal operation, there's a big array of contacts, which may or may not have been filtered by other operations that the user performs.  And the table view properly invokes cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the table cells that should be rendered while scrolling.

When the search bar is on display, the array is filtered differently (to match records that satisfy the search criteria).  And my point was that cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called and I return the exact same cell structure -- labels, content, etc.  Only in this case not all of the content gets rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the textLabel's text property appears to also bring the textLabel to the front.  Even though the text label does not appear to overlap with any of the content view's buttons, this is causing the buttons to disappear.  Forcing them to the front *after* the textLabel is updated makes the problem go away.

It is not clear why this behavior is only appearing in the search case and not in the normal case, but I was able to reproduce it in a simple change to the iOS "TableSearch" example.

Comment: nice to hear that you fixed it

Comment: awarding the bounty to yourself doesn't get your reputation points back.

Comment: I'm picking the answer.  The bounty isn't from me and will go wherever Ned wants it to go.

Comment: this tip save my day, thanks 
my problem was that upon upgrading to ios14 we had some legacy code that running with objective c , making the suitable cell totally from coding without autolayout

Answer (score 1):

you can check if

```
identifier in *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
```

is equalt to ***"My Identifier"*** from `[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"My Identifier"]`;  if not you can get empty cell, which you can use it's cell.imageView and cell.textLabel but does not have the contentView subviews.

Comment: The identifier matches and the cell does have a contentView subview to which I add my labels and buttons.  This works great when the cells are drawn normally but not when they're managed by the UISearchDisplayController.